# Java String.split() without specific symbol

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String like "3332255766122" which I want to have in an Array like this: 333,22,55,7,66,1,22

So, the String should be splitted in parts, whenever a new character appears. Is this possible?

My current approach was to check a letter, than check the next one, and if they are equal check also the next one and so on, if they are not equal, they previous equal ones are added to a list.

Comment: Yes. Possible. Any attempt ?

Comment: Not yet, usually I used String.Split(), but there I have to add a parameter which symbolizes the delimeter, which I don't have.

Comment: you'll need to create your own method. it's not that difficult.

Comment: Split won't work. Iterate over string and check with previous char, add delimeter.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but I thought there might be a better (more elegant) way. Thank you!

Comment: @I don't see any easy method than that other than some third-party util method.

Comment: no problem, that'll totally do it

Comment: You could probably get rid of the down vote by editing your question to show a method that you wrote to do the splitting and then asking if there is a better way to do it or by explaining how it could be done and why you don't want to do it that way. Right now it looks like you haven't done any work at all and are just asking us to give you the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with `split()` and some regex-magic:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( "3332255766122".split( "(?<=(.))(?!\\1)" ) ));
```

Output:

```
[333, 22, 55, 7, 66, 1, 22]
```

Regex breakdown:

- `(?<=x)` is a positive zero-width look-behind, so it will match the position right after the match for subexpression `x`
- `(.)` as epxression for `x` above is a capturing group that matches any character and captures it for the next step. In combination with the part above, i.e. `(?<=(.))` this means: "match any position after a character and capture that character into a group"
- `(?!x)` is a negative look-ahead which matches any position that is not followed by a match of subexpression `x`.
- `\1` is a back-reference to the match of the first capturing group (`(.)` in this case), so in combination with the part above, i.e. `(?!\1)`, this matches any position that does not match the character before

In words the expression would mean: "match any position after any character that is not followed by the same character".

Comment: Could you explain the regex pls?

Comment: @MuratK I'm already working on that :)

Comment: @MuratK.this should help http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: I was trying `"(?<=(.)\\1*)"` ... but the Pattern doesn't compile.  It says "look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 9".

Comment: @Pshemo yeah, that's what I used to help my memory for the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown!

Answer (score 5):

This could work for you :

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String s = "3332255766122";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\1*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }       
    }
```

O/P :

```
333
22
55
7
66
1
22
```

PS : I think *Thomas'* solution is better :)